# How do I cast a List from a subclass generic to a parent class generic?

Tags: list, java, downcast

I'm modifying open JDK to add features and I've run into this twice with no good solution.

There's a class named `JCStatement` which extends `JCTree`.

Issue: I want to cast a `List<JCStatement>` into a `List<JCTree>`.

It's clear that a class can reference one of its extensions, but when I have it on a List, it just doesn't work.

I used: `(List<JCTree>)((List<?>)params)` to cast, which works, but doesn't build on ant. IDE gives me the following warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<JCTree>
```

So this must be worked around somehow.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you cannot use typecasting, there are methods that can help you, for example `Collections.copy(List dest, List src)`. Find these methods and choose the best for you. Sorry for bad answer, cannot find them at this moment

Comment: I edited this to remove the extra example, which was un-necessary, and to cleanup the title question.

Comment: alaster, your solution almost worked, but I'd need a way to instantiate a `List<JCTree>` with enough space for the copy, List.nil() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the List, or generic types collections as general.

Simplest solution ever:

```
ListBuffer<JCTree> ls = new ListBuffer<JCTree>();
for(JCVariableDecl v : params){ ls.append(v); }
return ls.toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot make this cast.**

What happens if you cast a `List<JCStatement>` to a `List<JCTree>` and then you add a JCTree (non JCStatement) object to that list? It breaks the `List<JCStatement>` type safety.

Comment: +1 Edited for clarity.  If OP explains why he thinks this is the solution, we can try to help him find a better solution.  He hasn't provided enough information for us to know the way to solve the problem.

Comment: There are no other objects I'm supposed to insert into the List, adding one would probably break the compiler in some point.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you won't add any elements to the list -- so it will be type-safe -- then [`Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends E>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) will return a `List<E>`.

This is totally type-safe and legit, because it enforces the guarantee that you'll never add an illegal element to the list, and it's provided by the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

public class Program {
    public static void foo(List<? extends A> list) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        List<C> listC = new ArrayList<C>();
        List<? extends A> listX = (List<? extends A>) listB;
        List<? extends A> listY = (List<? extends A>) listC;

        foo(listA);
        foo(listB);
        foo(listC);
        foo(listX);
        foo(listY);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, even worse:
`The method appendList(List<JCTree>) in the type ListBuffer<JCTree> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-
  of ? extends JCTree>)`

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize that you don't have any control over the method signature in this case. My code sample would work if you were able to change the method signature to accept a `List<? extends JCTree>` instead of `List<JCTree>`. I'll leave this answer here *just in case* someone's finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you're really really sure it's safe by casting through the Raw Type

```
List<Number> listA = new LinkedList<Number>();
List<Integer> listB = new LinkedList<Integer>();
listA = (List<Number>)(List) listB;
```

I cannot imagine myself ever thinking that's a good solution to a problem, but it will do what you want, and there are some irritating limitations to compile time generics :)

There will always be a warning for a Unsafe cast, because what you're doing is in fact unsafe.  There is no way for the compiler to make it safe, you have to be sure of that yourself.