# Compile error with Java Generics and Apache Olingo 4

Tags: java, generics, olingo

I’ve extended some of the base classes of [Apache Olingo 4](http://olingo.apache.org/) (still in development) to allow for stronger typing.  However, my use of generics is causing an error that I didn’t expect.

I have a type parameter E that extends FooODataEntity which in turn implements the ODataEntity interface.  Since FooODataEntity is an ODataEntity (just more specific) I would expect this to compile with no issues.  However, getEntities() has a compilation error as shown in the code below.

Also, I would expect to be able to specify `List<E>` as a return type for my override of `getEntities()` but then I get a compile error saying:

`'getEntities()' in 'com.foo.restapi.client.olingo.FooEntitySet' clashes with 'getEntities()' in 'org.apache.olingo.commons.api.domain.v4.ODataEntitySet'; attempting to use incompatible return type`

What am I missing here?

FooODataEntitySet:

```
package com.foo.restapi.client.olingo;

import com.foo.restapi.client.FooODataEntity;
import com.foo.restapi.client.exceptions.FooRuntimeException;

import org.apache.olingo.commons.api.domain.v4.ODataAnnotation;
import org.apache.olingo.commons.api.domain.v4.ODataEntity;
import org.apache.olingo.commons.api.domain.v4.ODataEntitySet;
import org.apache.olingo.commons.core.domain.AbstractODataEntitySet;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FooEntitySet<E extends FooODataEntity> 
        extends AbstractODataEntitySet implements ODataEntitySet {

    private final List<E> entities = new ArrayList<E>();

    public FooEntitySet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ODataEntity> getEntities() {
        // compile error  
        // Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.List<E>', 
        // required: 'java.util.List<org.apache.olingo.commons.api.domain.v4.ODataEntity>'

        return entities;
    }
}
```

FooODataEntity:

```
package com.foo.restapi.client;

public class FooODataEntity extends AbstractODataPayload 
        implements ODataEntity, ODataSingleton {

    // code not shown
}
```

Comment: Could you include the imports from your class as well?

Comment: What about for `FooODataEntity`? If you don't have imports for it, then that's your problem. Make sure `FooODataEntity`'s source file includes the imports for `ODataEntity` and `ODataSingleton`.

Comment: imports were good, problem was misunderstanding of casting generics as per Powerlord's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason you can't do this.  While a `FooODataEntity` is an `ODataEntity`, a `List<FoodODataEntity>` is **not** a `List<ODataEntity>`.

Lets cover that in more detail:

Say I have this class:

```
public class BaconODataEntity implements ODataEntity {
    // Pretend I implement all the ODataEntity things
}
```

I can add an instance of `BaconODataEntity` into a `List<BaconODataEntity>` and a `List<ODataEntity>`... but not into a `List<FooODataEntity>`.

So, simply letting you cast a `List<FooODataEntity>` to a `List<ODataEntity>` would destroy the very type safety that generics are meant to introduce as I could then add a `BaconODataEntity` to it

So, how do you fix it?  Well, if you absolutely need your List to be a `List<E extends FooODataEntity>`, [create a new List and copy the elements into it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804635/15880) and return that list.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it showed where my thinking was wrong. I do need the list to extend `FooODataEntity` for another method so I copied into a new list of type `ODataEntity` as you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, definitely didn't think about it hard enough. :)